# Is there a specific name for this type of navigation?

Tags: usability, navigation, terminology, sidebar

Currently, I'm working on a project that requires a lot of **repeated navigational options**.

For example:

**System 1:**

- Transform;
- Require;
- Pipeline.

**System 2:**

- Transform;
- Require;
- Pipeline.

**System 3:**

- Transform;
- Require;
- Pipeline.

**And so on and on**, a good example of a solution I was able to find is what Jira and GitLab use:

[image]

[image]

Doesn't matter the board I select the navigation options are all the same but the content changes.

**Do you know how this type of navigation it's called?**

Comment: multi-level menus?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Question.

I think this navigation is used on the page layout called **Two Panel Layout.**

Refer to this article for more info.
https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/two-panel-selectors-for-easy-access-of-content

The menu extending more child elements is called **nested menu item**.